# How to differentiate between んい and に in romaji?

Tags: rōmaji

Occasionally I want to look up a word on [Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/) from a device where it is inconvenient to use a Japanese keyboard. The default is to interpret an input as romaji if possible, so that's usually not a problem, but a word like 音{おん}韻{いん} would be romanized as *onin*, which Jisho parses as おにん, not おんいん, and does not find the word I am looking for.

When actually entering the text, I would enter o-n-n-i-n-n, but *onnin*, would be the romanization of おんにん. Is there a standard way to differentiate between んい and に in situations like this?

Comment: Can you change which IME you're using on the device?  On Windows 10, onninn gets me おんいん.

Comment: @Andy The issue is not with an IME. If I'm actually typing kana, I can render it just fine. You can see what I was looking for from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not easy to input the right romaji to find a Japanese word especially when 'ん' is in the middle.

In the case of 'onin', you should place an apostrophe after the first 'n' to separate 'on' and 'in' and if you type "on'in", the [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%20on'in) will show it as [音韻]{おんいん}.

Answer (score 5):

If we go by what Japanese people use in practice, the standard way *when typing into an IME* is in fact exactly what you said. Double the "n" and type "onninn".

Linguists will probably frown at it, but it is what people do in practice. For instance, a Japanese mobile QWERTY keyboard with limited space will likely not even have an `'` key. You sometimes even see people do the double "n" when not using an IME because they're accustomed to it, and many people never bother learning "easy to read romanization for foreigners".